# Flask + mod_wsgi + httpd: All resources tried on DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, flask, mod-wsgi, error-log

#### In Brief

I have a WSGI script mounted at `/app`. If I request `/app/resource`, I get a correct response. But I **also** get an entry in my error log as if I had requested `/resource`. What could cause this?

#### In Detail

I have a Flask application deployed with Apache 2.4 + mod_wsgi on AWS EC2:

1. The application lives at `/my/app/path`
2. The `app.wsgi` file lives at `/var/www/wsgi` and points to `/my/app/path`
3. The Apache config for the `www.website.com` vhost points to the WSGI script:
   `WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/wsgi/app.wsgi`

When I GET `www.website.com/app/some_resource/...`, **I receive the expected response for that resource** with code `200`.

However, when I check the Apache error logs, I find loads of entries for denied requests, e.g.:

`[authz_core:error] [pid XXXXX] [client XXXXX] XXXXX: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/some_resource`

The logged errors correspond 1-to-1 with requests that, as stated, come back `200`.

Now, `/var/www/html` is the default DocumentRoot, but the request is sent to the `/app` location, and is correctly passed-to and handled-by the WSGI application via the alias directive.

And so: Why might I find these entries in my error logs, in which the `/app` path is removed, and the resource path appended directly (and correctly denied) on the root?

#### Follow-Up

To respond to Graham's suggestions in the comments:

1. There are no Apache rewrite rules defined.
2. Apache is not setup with MultiViews
3. These are JSON resources; the errors are not the result of sub-requests from a loaded document.
4. Issue persists without symlinks.

#### Update

A colleague tells me he has encountered the same issue on AWS EC2 instances.

Comment: What are the resources? Look in the access log to see the URLs that have 4xx errors. Browsers will automatically request things like ``favicon.ico`` etc and depending on permissions that can fail.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton The example GET request, and resulting record in the error log, are accurate templates (including the ellipsis). Substitute an arbitrary string for `some_resource` in the example GET request, and a corresponding line will appear in the error log.

Comment: Are you saying that '...' literally appears in the URL? Sounds a bit like what ever page you are accessing is then fetching other resources but the URL for those isn't being constructed by your application properly.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton No, I am saying that what follows the final `/` before the ellipsis in the example request does not affect the entry in the error_log.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton To clarify: my application is working correctly. In order for my application to work correctly, Apache/mod_wsgi must be correctly parsing incoming URLs, stripping the mount-path (sub-URL, aka "`/app`"), and passing the remainder (aka "`/some_resource/...`") to the WSGI application.

In which case, why does the error_log contain this entry in which the "remainder" is simply appended to the DocumentRoot, with apparently no effect on the handling of the request?

Comment: Do you have any Apach rewrite rules defined? Or is Apache setup to use MultiViewsMatch? If you use ``curl`` from the command line to access the URL, do you still see multiple requests and the failures? If you see them with ``curl`` then it is something strange about your Apache setup. If you don't see them from ``curl`` but do from browser, suggestive of sub requests from main resources. BTW, if by points to you mean a symlink, they can sometimes cause issues with Apache resource matching. Can you not use the symlink.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112281/discussion-between-this-vidor-and-graham-dumpleton).

Comment: What does the vhost config look like?

Comment: @user866762 I am leery of being more descriptive, as a matter of security. What would you be looking out for?